# Spring Data Repository: Detached entity passed to persist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

A profile object has a list of tasks. 
When saving a new profile, the list of tasks should be also synchronized with Database (*inserted* or *updated*). The problem is the profile-repository's **save()**-method allows only the one or the other method depends on the cascade property set above the attribute (*CascadeType.PERSIST or MERGE*).

The Profile class

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class AbstractProfile implements Profile {
    ...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Task> tasks;

    ..
```

JUnit-Test class

```
public class ProfileTaskRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired 
    private ProfileRepository profileRepo;    //extends JpaRepository
    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository taskRepo;          //extends JpaRepository

    @Test // ->this test passes
    public void testCreateProfileWithNewTask() {

        //profileData and taskData hold dummy data. They return new objects
        AbstractProfile interview = profileData.createITInterviewProfile();
        Task questionTask = taskData.createInterviewQuestionTask();

        //add new task to profile and save
        interview.addTask(questionTask);
        profileRepo.save(interview);

        //task repository confirms the insertion
        assertTrue(taskRepo.count() == 1); 
    }

    @Test // ->this test fails
    public void testCreateProfileWithExistingTask() {

        //first create task and save in DB
        Task questionTask = taskData.createInterviewQuestionTask();  // transient obj
        taskRepo.save(questionTask);  // questionTask becomes detached

        // then create a new profile and add the existing task.
        // the problem is the existing task is now detached)
        AbstractProfile interview = profileData.createITInterviewProfile();
        interview.addTask(questionTask);

        profileRepo.save(interview); // !!! this throws an exception
    }
```

I suppose the **questionTask**-object becomes detached when taskRepo saves it in DB and then closes the session.

Exception:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: *.Task; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: *.Task
...
```

The **profileRepo.save()** should be able to handle both **insertion** and **update** of list of tasks. Is there a elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: What is `Task` ? Is it a class you have designed ? Can you post that code ?

Answer (score 2):

You should put `@Transactional` attributes on the test class to avoid the exception.

```
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration
public class ProfileTaskRepositoryTest {
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This isnt needed for test class. It should have been added in TaskRepository that actually extends the JpaRepository.

Comment: In the question it is described that ProfileRepository and TaskRepository extends from JpaRepository which is an interface. Had it been the case CreateProfileWithExistingTask was a service class method then yes @Transactional attributes should have been on the service class and there was no need to put it in the test class unless you have a requirement to run tests in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

try cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }

Comment: I am afraid it throws the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate session has expired;

Use

```
spring.datasource.removeAbandoned=false
```

or

```
spring.datasource.removeAbandonedTimeout=...
```